# On WinXP: Map a path on one drive letter to another path on another drive

Tags: windows-xp

This is all I want to do:

Take Java, which is on a USB drive, and map it to my local C drive.

f:\java

and map it to

c:\java

Naturally, for obtuse reasons, I can't copy it. (there is no existing c:\java) If it were on a happy non-existent drive letter like w, this wouldn't be a problem, but it needs to be the local C drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mount a partition as a folder instead of a drive letter. For example, if your entire F drive was what you wanted, you can mount it as c:\Java instead of F.

This is done from the disk management console, which for example you can find in compmgmt.msc in XP Pro.

EDIT: Another option is the MKLINK command for Vista and above. It's a native cmd.exe command, so it's not PowerShell friendly.

```
    MKLINK /J c:\Java f:\Java
```

Comment: Very close: if I didn't have other files I needed on the drive, I could, but I actually have two folders I need to mount on my c:\ that point to the f:\

Comment: @altCognito If that's the case, you can try the MKLINK command, which is part of the cmd.exe shell in Vista and later. "MKLINK /J c:\Java f:\Java" should work.

Comment: On Windows XP, directory junctions can be created using [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768) instead of `mklink`.

Comment: Ooh, good call on Junction. That must be a new one. Sysinternals to the rescue again!

Comment: Junction. That's the one that did the trick.